# Integer to decimal with 2 decimal places

Tags: sqlite

I want to cast an integer to a decimal with 2 decimal places.

I've tried with:

```
select cast(sum as decimal(18,2)) FROM ...
```

But it won't work. Is there any wrong in the Query ?

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/29c61/1)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with this query is that SQLite [uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); this just casts to REAL.

To round a number, use the [round](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round) function:

```
SELECT round(sum, 2) FROM ...
```

A database should not be concerned with formatting data; it might be a better idea to format the number in your program.

Comment: Yes i know, but unfortainly this is my only option in this case.